# Which Safari version corresponds to which WebKit version?

Tags: safari, google-analytics, user-agent

Here is what Google Analytics says about the popularity of different Safari versions on my website:

```
Safari version     Visits
=========================
533.21.1           48.82%
6533.18.5          19.52%
533.19.4            8.15%
534.5               3.82%
533.20.27           3.50%
534.48.3            3.10%
531.21.10           2.43%
533.18.5            2.30%
6531.22.7           1.00%
531.9               0.89%
```

But these are actually WebKit versions. Is there a table somewhere to help me to translate them to Safari versions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MDN Web Docs GitHub lists Safari versions with the corresponding WebKit version: https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/blob/main/browsers/safari.json

Comment: Not sure how I missed that! Thanks. Any ideas on why GA reports Safari by layout engine version, but every other browser by browser version?

Comment: For iOS versions it appears you need to disregard the thousands number - so for 6531.22.7, just look for 531.22.7 = Safari 4.0.5 (or for a newer version: 8536.25 ~> 536.25 = Safari 6).

Comment: confused for this numbering scheme...

Comment: Sadly, that page has been deleted as of 29 November 2023. Here is the last version of the table: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Safari_version_history&oldid=1186257925

Comment: On https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/blob/main/browsers/safari.json you'll find a list mapping Safari versions to WebKit versions, that is still maintained.