# What Safari version is Google Analytics referring to?

Tags: safari, google-analytics, mobile-safari

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132845/which-safari-version-corresponds-to-which-webkit-version), I was able to find the Safari version for most of the Webkits (all the 3 digit Webkits) that Google Analytics refers to. However, there are a few that are not listed in the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history).

Here is a snapshot of what Analytics is showing me.

**What version/OS of Safari do the 7534 and 6533 Webkits refer to?**

```
1.  7534.48.3   45.50%  
2.  534.57.2    12.51%
3.  534.55.3    8.44%
4.  533.22.3    6.60%
5.  534.52.7    4.96%
6.  6533.18.5   4.95%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Google Analytics added an extra number in front of the version number. IMO `7534.48.3` refers to `534.48.3` and `6533.18.5` to `533.18.5`.

These 2 versions are respectively Safari 5.1 and 5.0.2, which makes sense in regard to their market share.

You could try contacting them through [Google Analytics Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/analytics).

Comment: That does make sense, in regards to their market share. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The first digit corresponds to the version of OSX that the webkit was built for.

6533.18.5 would be for Mac OS X v10.6 "Snow Leopard"

7534.48.3 would be for Mac OS X v10.7 "Lion"

If you have one that starts with an 8 and four digits would be Mac OS X v10.8 "Mountain Lion"

etc.

Comment: This also applies to mobile Safari. The trick is that the first digit is two ahead of the iOS version. So, 6533.18.5 means iOS 4, 7534.48.3 means iOS 5, etc. Wonder how long it's gonna be until Google cleans up all this up for us... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you google "safari version" plus one of these numbers, you'll see that the Safari version with 4 digits in the main version number are iOS versions. See here: http://www.useragentstring.com/Safari5.0.2_id_18120.php
Best,